# Excel Formatting issues

Tags: excel

I am about 1500 data split into for different cells. I am trying to join them when I do that the zero value before the number isn't getting added.

Say for example:

```
 | B  | C  | D  | E  |   
1| 90 | B8 | 6C | 04 |
```

and all the cells are in number format.

I do the following: `E1&D1&C1&B1` I get the results like `46CB890` instead of `046CB890`. I can add a zero to the value but there are 1500 data and I don't how many have this issue. How to solve this? so that I get 0 while joining the values.

Thanks!

Comment: Are all the values exactly 2 characters? If so you could use something like `=TEXT(B1,"00")&TEXT(C1,"00")` If you can, you should also just be able to convert all the of the cells format to text and it should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of all the cells to text (fill E1 with 04).
Re-use the formula and it should work.